Issue with signing JSON web tokens
I am using node version v16.3.2, and trying to generate a bearer token using the jsonwebtoken library.
Here is my code:
require("dotenv").config();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// this throws an error (secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256)
const token = jwt.sign(
      { iss: process.env.ID, client_id: process.env.ID },
      process.env.TOKEN,
      { algorithm: "RS256" },
    );

// the second time around, this works fine!
const token2 = jwt.sign(
      { iss: process.env.ID, client_id: process.env.ID },
      process.env.TOKEN,
      { algorithm: "RS256" },
    );

I am not sure what could be happening. The first attempt to call jwt.sign fails, while the second succeeds in generating a valid token. I have verified that the process.env.ID and process.env.TOKEN variables are properly loaded after the require("dotenv") line.
-- EDIT: reproducible example --
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const key = `
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

const id = "e67e5eed-c9f9-4807-af63-2bcacd3a445e";

After the above setup:
> const token = jwt.sign({iss: id, client_it: id}, key, {algorithm:"RS256"});
Uncaught Error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/home/apps/olyxbase-test/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:130:22)
> const token2 = jwt.sign({iss: id, client_it: id}, key, {algorithm:"RS256"});
undefined
> token2
'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJlNjdlNWVlZC1jOWY5LTQ4MDctYWY2My0yYmNhY2QzYTQ0NWUiLCJjbGllbnRfaXQiOiJlNjdlNWVlZC1jOWY5LTQ4MDctYWY2My0yYmNhY2QzYTQ0NWUiLCJpYXQiOjE3MTM5Njk3NjB9.CoyxmhMKPFPdK6tv5lOtiwIPXOIRb_mRjntJI0snMW-nHdrZ-j3HS7n2_2en4KXz8rH9Baphn-S2a4EH9ccZvlPLpJyVA7jkWhRxQjs_SRkT17PtWOxLtiA90XTEhR14vDWQwwOAL9vIVTixjHiIXtSXH-B5nZHMZYJC5eCVowCtF4cWicFcXNqQ8DNnmCl7x4oKTVkljqtnVNSU4llWCvQh-GG2HHom60Mq3wbsQE2D2XA_koF8BSgsfh7HluyxkFJK5D4wlJF4BaEvIKTdj64zy25L3QYbXzCgDb80KcF-v0cGhRMZ6tz6mN35w848Y39wS_I8S0VV5-CGAGOeIPjxTsvucSUqVkAaZvTEADBlzxOSPHrpL5P-4ksczNZGOvvG7N-FK0urX6zxi6mkzEGQLEjDn9FswLBvjunH2blYkJa25r18eSl4tlkefGI8PspIO2f8EjWZtRo_R_B5jaFeANtpHay9rUBeeV4e5WlYPJMblVVCg0vxFmyMvG1OBOdLkpgS-r8CUVmDziY3oYPJDtCKf2nVBwMacKl4vUAMf92LmGOEV5UJW8vELj67KSxEwgY604kXjbl3puw0YBKwbOtg-7I3Gfwgt5rANnR1UiVvG0aiVygvvtzlF6SIPUKuEQZtzt6Oloe4nwf77eAi9ngSeaq71ufYqThPg00'


does process.env.TOKEN realy contain a PEM encoded private key? Ie something like -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- encoded key etc -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ? If yes, it should work also for the first attempt, if not, I don't see how the second attempt may succeed.

process.env.token indeed contains a PEM key with the format you are describing, which is why I am also stumped

And is this your exact code, ie the two calls to sign just one after the other? How may that even reach the second call, if the first call throws an exception?

Exactly, It seems the somehow your sign function runs before the env variables are loaded. is this the exact code or you simplified?

I ran the above code at the command line after opening a node shell. EDIT: so essentially ran four commands, first the dotenv, then importing jwt, then the first sign command, then the second.

entire code at once? including token and token2?

does the token in your .env file contain linebreaks or \n characters?

Yes it does. The PEM private key has a new line character at the end of each line, except the very last line which just ends with -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Does your key have a passphrase by any chance? Internally, jsonwebtoken first calls createPrivateKey() and if that fails, createSecretKey(). And createPrivateKey() fails if you don't specify a passphrase in the call when using a passphrased key, which jsonwebtoken doesn't... And obviously, createSecretKey() call is invalid here, as the error message says

What happens when you replace the env variables with strings?

There isn't a passphrase

@jabaa I tried it again by replacing process.env.ID directly with the string in the jwt.sign call, and instead of process.env.TOKEN, I used a string variable I created by copying my env variable. Getting the same outcome.. first time works, second time doesn't.

Can you try generating a new RSA key for testing purposes and reproduce this bevaviour with the new key? If yes can you then share the respective .env file containg this test key. Or is your current key by any chance "shareable" (ie  just used for testing purposes and not used anywhere else)

I cannot reproduce this behaviour with a test key i just generated, and I don't understand how two subsequent calls to jwt.sign with the exact same input would throw an error first but then succeed ...

Can you remove the dotenv package from your question and provide a [mcve] with hardcoded strings?

@jabaa - just edited my post to provide a new key and ID I generated, which give rise to the issue.

Works fine for me ...  (being on windows and node 18.15 though)

I also noticed it working with an upgraded node version. But the server this is executing on is on v16.3.2

Also tried on a linux with node 14.17. Works fine there too.

I get the same error on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zdjiqj?file=index.js But it also doesn't work the second time. It looks like the key isn't correct.

@jabaa I see the errors on stackblitz. But with the very same key, it works on my local machine and anoter linux server (also the first time).  Not sure whether the jsonwebtoken somehow internally uses openssl somehow? And something is going wrong there?

I would start this code in the debugger and analyze the problem or create an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues

Here are some debugging results: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2051#issuecomment-1867139666 The current best solution is to update Node or downgrade Ubuntu.
